# [java]why hashmap's data come back after I add some data eventhough I hava already clear the hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class readBin {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();


File targetfile = new File("d:\\d2012.bin");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(targetfile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2097152];
    int byteread = 0;
    String bufferString = "";

    ArrayList<HashMap> arr = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    ArrayList arrstr = new ArrayList();
    HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
    ArrayList<String> cttarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] strarr = new String[2];
    ArrayList<String> valarr = new ArrayList<>();
    //It's all init above,below comes the file reading
    bufferString = br.readLine();
    while(bufferString != null){
        //if data readed this line from the file is not "*newrecord" or ""
        if(!bufferString.equals("*NEWRECORD")&&!bufferString.equals("")){
            //according to the need,make use of these data
            strarr = bufferString.split("=");
            switch (strarr[0].trim()) {
            case "UI":
                hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(), strarr[1].trim());
                break;
            case "MH":
                hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(), strarr[1].trim());
                break;
            case "AQ":
                String[] valuearr = strarr[1].split(" ");
                hashmap.put(strarr[0], valuearr);
                break;
            case "ENTRY":
                bufferString = bufferString.split("\\|")[0].toString();
                //if key named ENTRY has already existed,update the data
                if (hashmap.containsKey(strarr[0].trim())) {
                    ArrayList<String> templist = ((ArrayList<String>)hashmap.get(strarr[0].trim()));
                    templist.add(bufferString.split("=")[1].trim());
                    hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(), templist);
                //or insert it 
                } else {
                    cttarr.add(bufferString);
                    hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(),cttarr);
                }
                break;
            case "MS":
                hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(), strarr[1].trim());
                break;
            case "MN":
                //as ENTRY do
                if (hashmap.containsKey(strarr[0].trim())) {
                    ArrayList<String> templist =     ((ArrayList<String>)hashmap.get(strarr[0].trim()));
                    templist.add(strarr[1].trim());
                    hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(), templist);
                } else {
                    cttarr.add(strarr[1].trim());
                    hashmap.put(strarr[0].trim(),cttarr);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        } else if(hashmap.size() != 0) {
            //if it equals to *newrecord or "",init the hashmap again
            arr.add(hashmap);
            hashmap = new HashMap();
        }
        bufferString = br.readLine();
        if (bufferString == null) {
            arr.add(hashmap);
        }
    }
    ArrayList arrresult = arr;
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(time2-time1);
    String ui = (String) arr.get(0).get("MH");
    ArrayList<String> entrys = (ArrayList<String>) arr.get(0).get("ENTRY");
    int len = arr.size();
    System.out.println(ui);
    System.out.println(len);
}

public String getbs(){
    return "";
}
}
```

I want to iterate the data from the file and add them to the hashmap,after updating the hashmap to the arrayList,init the hashmap again.but from the result ,it seems the data in the hashmap wont clear.

Comment: Are you using java 7? and please elaborate your problem little  more

Comment: Please provide more information otherwise it's hard to help

Comment: if there are 2 records in the file and ENTRY = 1,ENTRY = 2.

Comment: I will get 1,2 in one record instead of getting them seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK，Now I know how important it is to learn English well.

I got the point now,in collection ,it is always reference instead of entity,so I shouldn't write code as this

`ArrayList<String> templist = ((ArrayList<String>)hashmap.get(strarr[0].trim()));`

when I turned it to `ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<String>((ArrayList<String>)hashmap.get(strarr[0].trim()));`,it runs good.

Answer (score 0):

quite obviously, as new HashMap() is not known to retain data from a previous instance

```
    } else if(hashmap.size() != 0) {
        //if it equals to *newrecord or "",init the hashmap again
        arr.add(hashmap);
        hashmap = new HashMap();
    }
```

is not executed when you want it to be executed. So check the format of your input file, and/or try to debug.

Comment: it's normally executed when i want,but after I use {hashmap = new HashMap()},the data I added to the hashmap will maintain when I add other data the next time

Comment: You say after `HashMap m = new HashMap(); m.put("a", "b"); HashMap m = new HashMap(); m.put("c", "d");` m will contain keys "a" and "c"?